# Create emulator-x86 Image on Android

Tags: android, x86, emulation

We all know ARM emulation is really slow. I just noticed a `emulator-x86` binary in tools/. I tried to run an image with it but I get an error saying I need an x86 image.

I cannot find a way to create one using the `android` binary. Is there way?

Comment: The emulator-x86 is for Google TV. It has specific development machine requirements (Linux, KVM, and the right sort of Intel chip). And, there appears to be a bug in the new r14 development tools: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=20963

Comment: Check this blog: [Yafla.com](http://blog.yafla.com/The_Android_Development_Tools_Add_x86_Support) he talks about a more interesting reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you've already found an answer to this :) But just in case, and for future readers:

1) Install `Intel x86 System Image` using the SDK manager , as shown here:

[image]

2) Optional: From the `Extras` subdirectory in the SDK manager, download and install `Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM)`. This will make android emulators with x86 images run even faster. You will need to configure it, Android documentation has [detailed info on this](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#acceleration).

3) Create a new virtual device using AVD. Make sure you select `Intel Atom(x86)` in the CPU/ABI field.

4) Run it and enjoy improved performance!